# AWK Match & Split not finding string pattern

Tags: awk

Passing the following commands I would expect the first to split the string (which is also a regex) into two array elements and the second command (match) to print [[:blank:]].

```
echo "new[[:blank:]]+File\(" | awk '{ split($0, a, "[[:blank:]]"); print a[1]}'
```

prints the whole string as it has not split

```
echo "new[[:blank:]]+File\(" | awk '{ match($0, /[[:blank:]]/, m)}END{print m[0]}'
```

prints nothing

What am I missing here?

***UPDATE***

I'm calling an awk script with the following command;

```
awk -v regex1=new[[:blank:]]+File\( -f parameterisedRegexAwkScript.awk "$file" >> "output.txt"
```

Then in the my script I attempt to split on the string literal with the following command;

```
len = split(regex1, regex, /[[:blank:]]/, seps
```

but when I print len it's value is 1 when I would have expected it to be 2

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. Your string `echo "new[[:blank:]]+File\(" ` is not being taken as a regexp its taken as literal string in echo, could you please show more clear samples of input and expected output so that we can get better understanding of your question, thank you(Not my downvote btw).

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13, thanks for your response. I've updated the question with a more detailed input and output. Hope this helps, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "new[[:blank:]]+File\(" | awk '{ split($0, a, "[[:blank:]]"); print a[1]}'
```

3rd argument for [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) works like setting `FS` in `BEGIN`, so in this case you instruct to split at any whitespace, you need to escape `[` and `]`. Let `file.txt` content be

```
new[[:blank:]]+File\(
```

then

```
awk '{split($0, a, "\\[\\[:blank:\\]\\]"); print a[1]}' file.txt
```

output

```
new
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: The 3rd arg to split() is a regexp, not a string, so use regexp `/` rather than string `"` delimiters. You also don't need to escape a `]` as it's only a regexp metachar if preceded by an opening `[`. Your `split()` call should then be `split($0, a, /\[\[:blank:]]/)` instead of `split($0, a, "\\[\\[:blank:\\]\\]")`.

Comment: @EdMorton this worked thanks. I do find that the value of a[2] is 'File(' instead of 'File\\('. Even when the command is updated to pass regex1='new[[:blank:]]+File\\\(' I get awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('. But when I try regex1="new[[:blank:]]+File\\\\\\\(" or regex1='new[[:blank:]]+File\\\\(' it sets a[2] to 'File\\\('

Comment: You're welcome. Of course but that's a different question so please  ask a new question about that if you'd like help with it.

Comment: @EdMorton - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111174/attempting-to-pass-an-escape-char-to-awk-as-a-variable I hope it makes more sense now